# num rows have trouble entering how many are

Tags: c#

this is how I have come into a problem, I would like to find out how many uses there into my website

I've tried to do it like this.

```
SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = conn1;

    cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM brugere";

    conn1.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader3 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader3.HasRows)
    {
        LabelBrugerantal.Text = reader3["id"].ToString();
    }
    conn1.Close();
```

It is such that it appears with an error here:

id

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: id

Source Error:

```
Line 67:         if (reader3.HasRows)
Line 68:         {
Line 69:             LabelBrugerantal.Text = reader3["id"].ToString();
Line 70:         }
Line 71:         conn1.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no column `id` returned on your query. You could do something like:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM brugere";
```

But that sounds weird :-)

The preferred way to do what you want is [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx). Your code would be like this (untested):

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM brugere";
// ...
LabelBrugerantal.Text = ((Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
```

No need to open a reader and check for the returned rows when you are getting a single scalar value from your query

Comment: Thanks for fast and nice help!! :)

Comment: It's not the preferable way to get a count though. I'll edit my answer